# how to delete all characters starting from the nth position for every word using bash?

Tags: bash

I have a file containing 1,700,000 words. I want to do naive stemming of the words, if a word's length is more than 6 characters, I delete all characters after 6th position. For example:

```
Input:
Everybody is around
Everyone keeps talking 

Output: 
Everyb is around
Everyo keeps talkin
```

I wrote the following script:

```
INPUT=train.txt
while read line; do
for word in $line; do
new="$(echo $word | awk '{print substr($0,1,6);exit}')"
echo -n $new >> train_stem_6.txt
echo -n ' ' >> train_stem_6.txt
done
echo   ' ' >> train_stem_6.txt
done < "$INPUT"
```

This answers the question perfectly, but it is extremely slow, and since I have 1,700,000 words, it takes forever.
Is there a faster way to do this using bash script.

Thanks a lot,

Comment: I cannot test right now, but your process is slow because of the additional processes started. Consider substring selection using `bash`: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html

Comment: What about hyphenated words ? Is there any punctuation ?

Comment: I think your code was slow because of the high number of fork induced by your algorithm. `awk` can read files directly so you should be able to refactor using only one awk command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you consider using sed?

```
sed -r 's/([a-zA-Z]{6})[a-zA-Z]+/\1/g'
```

Comment: only need a single 6 in `{}`

Comment: Your Regex assumes words consist of ASCII-7 letters only. The OP assumes words are whitespace-separated.

Comment: How much quicker is this going to be?

Comment: @Bernhard, this needs to be tested. But at least this solution doesn't create external process for each word.

Comment: @Bernhard Almost any other method is significantly faster than a while read loop.

Comment: @gudok I am not super familiar with sed. Thanks a lot, that is super helpful. This is 1000 times faster. One 6 in {} does the job as well.

Comment: @user10610: While `sed` is a good answer generally, be aware that this answer works with a very different definition of "word".

Comment: @gudok Ah, yeah, somewhere in my head I though you were going to replace this in his loop. Of course not :)

Comment: @DevSolar yes that's a good point. The file I have has no special characters and no punctuation. Exactly like the example, words separated by a space.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this gnu awk using custom `RS`:

```
awk -v RS='[[:space:]]' '{ORS=RT; print substr($0, 1, 6)}' file

Everyb is around
Everyo keeps talkin
```

---

Timings of 3 commands on 11 MB input file:

**sed:**

```
time sed -r 's/([a-zA-Z]{6})[a-zA-Z]+/\1/g' file >/dev/null

real    0m2.913s
user    0m2.878s
sys     0m0.020s
```

**awk command by @andlrc:**

```
time awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){$i=substr($i, 1, 6)}}1' file >/dev/null

real    0m1.191s
user    0m1.174s
sys     0m0.011s
```

**My suggested awk command:**

```
time awk -v RS='[[:space:]]' '{ORS=RT; print substr($0, 1, 6)}' file >/dev/null

real    0m1.926s
user    0m1.905s
sys     0m0.013s
```

So both awk commands are taking pretty much same time to finish the job and sed tends to be slower on bigger files.

---

3 commands on 167mb file

```
$ time awk -v RS='[[:space:]]+' 'RT{ORS=RT} {$1=substr($1, 1, 6)} 1' test > /dev/null

real    0m29.070s
user    0m28.898s
sys     0m0.060s
$ time awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){$i=substr($i, 1, 6)}}1' test >/dev/null

real    0m13.897s
user    0m13.805s
sys     0m0.036s

$ time sed -r 's/([a-zA-Z]{6})[a-zA-Z]+/\1/g' test > /dev/null

real    0m40.525s
user    0m40.323s
sys     0m0.064s
```

Comment: This will be slower than almost any other awk solution due to not using default RS.

Comment: How is not using default `RS` making it slower?

Comment: It is optimised for default RS and FS. Try the other awk answer and this on a large file and check the time difference in completing.

Comment: I created a 11M file and ran all the answers. Posted timings in my answer above.

Comment: can i post my results in your answer to show you timings on my machine for a 167M file? You can delete them, just hard to show results in a comment.

Comment: Yes sure, please go ahead

Comment: This is a very interesting comparison. I didn't know that using a non-default RS and FS would penalize this much, nor that `sed` would be this slower.

Answer (score 3):

You can use awk for this:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){$i=substr($i, 1, 6)}}1' train.txt
```

Breakdown:

```
{                          
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {      # Iterate over each word
    $i = substr($i, 1, 6);  # Shrink it to a maximum of 6 characters
  }                         
}                           
1                           # Print the row
```

This will however treat `Awesome,` as a word and therefore remove `e,`

Comment: Will count every character that is not `[[:space:]]`, so all punctuation.

Comment: Not before i had commented.

Comment: @DevSolar Can't be sure OP knows or wants the limitations of their own code.

Answer (score 0):

Pure **bash**, (i.e. not POSIX), as a one-liner:

```
while read x ; do set -- $x ; for f in $* ; do echo -n ${f:0:6}" " ; done ; echo ; done < train.txt
```

...and the same code reformatted for clarity:

```
while read x ; do
    set -- $x
    for f in $* ; do 
        echo -n ${f:0:6}" "
    done
    echo
done < train.txt
```

Note: repeated whitespace becomes a single space.

Test run, first make a function using above code, with standard input:

```
len6() { while read x ; do set -- $x ; for f in $* ; do echo -n ${f:0:6}" " ; done ; echo ; done ; }
```

Invoke:

```
COLUMNS=90 man bash | tail | head -n 5 | len6
```

Output:

```
gracef when proces suspen is attemp When a proces is stoppe the 
shell immedi execut the next comman in the sequen It suffic to 
place the sequen of comman betwee parent to force it into a subshe 
which may be stoppe as a unit.
```

Comment: Slow going though.  Takes about 8 minutes to chug through 167MB of concatenated _man bash_.

Comment: POSIX version (no _bash_isms): `len6() { while read x ; do set -- $x ; for f in $* ; do n=${f%${f#??????}} ; echo -n "${n:-${f}} " ; done ; echo ; done ; }`.  Running in _dash_ it takes about 2m to chug through that same big file.